# How to change URI of WAR file in EAR file in MyEclipse?

Tags: eclipse, web-deployment-project, myeclipse, maven-ear-plugin

We have following projects:

> office - web application project
>   console - web application project

MyEclipse by default deploys these web applications to following locations:

```
C:\tools\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\web\deploy\office.war  
C:\tools\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\web\deploy\console.war
```

But in **ant build** and in our deployment scripts we use different names for war files:

```
devoffice.war  
devconsole.war
```

Now we are going not only build these two war files but we are going to create enterprise application **devapp** that will include both of these web applications:

> devapp - enterprise application project

In EAR we describe web applications in META-INF\application.xml
I created following application.xml:

```
<application >
  <display-name>devapp</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>devoffice.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/office</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>devconsole.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/console</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```

This application.xml works in case if we build EAR and WAR files by ant build procedure.
But this **application.xml** cannot be used from Eclipse because by default Eclipse creates **office.war** and **console.war** files but not **devoffice.war** and **devconsole.war**.

Is it possible to change the name of module in enterprise application?

Answer (score 1):

In the EAR project in eclipse, go to Properties / Deployment Assembly. 
You can edit the Deploy path for the WAR projects to any WAR file name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you would change the names of the projects as part of the build without the help of a build tool like ant or maven.

If you were using Maven, you could use the `bundleFileName` element of the Maven ear plugin's configuration to set an explicit name for the wars in the build of the ear, described here http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/howto.html

It seems like an unusual thing to want to do, so just in case you are actually interested in changing the webapp context roots, you can set that in the ear file itself as described here http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/webguide/r2/en/html/ch06.html

Comment: No - I am not interested in changing the webapp context root. We already use context root with name different than name of web application. I am interested in changing on name of war file.